# Printing Soviet-era Russian military maps at original scale

Tags: software-recommendations, printing, jpg

I have some Soviet era maps of my country that are very detailed. I have access to a plotter and would like to make a hard copy for my hiking trips but have issues getting the resolution/map scale to fit just right.

What app can I use to get the JPEG image as close to its scale as possible?

Comment: Have you had a look at the scale?

Comment: You could use the georeferencer in QGIS.

Comment: Tje scale is 1:25000

Comment: you may try inkscape and set the printing parameters